# jQuery not showing requested data on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

This is pretty much a beginner question. I've bound a little glyphicon to a click event to show some data on click. I've bound stuff to events a million times, but this time it isn't working for some funny reason. Anyway, the click trigger works pretty well, I've tried putting an alert in the callback and it's alright, but it's just the stuff I want to be shown that's not showing.

Anyway, here's my code:

```
<div class="options">
    <span id="resize-toggle" class="glyphicon glyphicon-resize-small valign-middle pointer" title="Resize images during the upload"></span> 
    <span id="thumb-toggle" class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust valign-middle pointer" title="Adjust the output thumnail width measured in pixels"></span>

    <div id="thumb-options" class="hidden">
        &nbsp;
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group mg-top" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><input type="radio" id="width-90" value="90">90</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs active"><input type="radio" id="width-110" value="110">110</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><input type="radio" id="width-130" value="130">130</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><input type="radio" id="width-160" value="160">160</label>
                <label class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><input type="radio" id="width-200" value="200">200</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the LESS:

```
.options {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    min-width: 500px;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid black;

    .form-group {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
    }

    #thumb-options {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

So, the `#thumb-toggle` is supposed to bring up `#thumb-options`. I've tried using classes beforehand, but I became desperate and started trying it with IDs.

My original intention is to make the radio buttons slide from the right, pushing the little glyphicons along the way.

Could someone please help me find the issue why the jQuery isn't working and how to achieve that slide to the right effect?

This is the jQuery I've been using:

```
$('#thumb-toggle').click(function(){
    alert('Here we are'); // Works!
    $('#thumb-options').fadeIn('fast'); // This doesn't work
});
```

Comment: Maybe the class="hidden" forces to hide the div?

Comment: does `$('#thumb-options').removeClass('hidden');` work? Is there more than one div with the id "thumb-options"?

Comment: @Tim Yes, that works! Why aren'tt `fadeIn`, `toggle` or `show` not working in this case?

Comment: Because the class="hidden" forces to hide the div as I said above

Comment: @Duigi sometimes wierd things happen with the cascading. Jquery is using a style rule that is less specific than the one for your class hiddden, but without seeing specifics, I can't explain exactly why. I imagine erikrunia's answer will also work (the second suggestion).

Comment: @Dugi The methods `fadeIn`, `toggle` and `show` all apply the stylizing `display:none` on (hide) or `display:block` (show) on the #thumb-options node, overwriting the `display` property.  There must be something in the `.hidden` class that's forcing the code to be hidden beyond just using `display:none` (such as `visibility:hidden`, or some size / scaling / etc.), which is why you should use `style="display:none"` instead.

Comment: @RayanBouajram Actually no. `.hidden` only contains `display: none;`.

Comment: @Dugi Looks like you're using bootstrap.  There could be more than one `.hidden` class in your CSS. The bootstrap library code does show its default to `.hidden { display: none !important; visibility: hidden !important; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is **[a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Gz9M/2/)** for what is descibed below. It is a simplified version of yours that is working.

You didn't show the `hidden` class, but the problem may be that you are using `FadeIn` on an element that is `invisible`. If you want the element to be invisible and therefore contribute to the layout of the dom then you should use  something like:

```
$('#thumb-options').css({opacity: 0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
```

If you want to use FadeIn then you will need the `$('#thumb-options')` to initially have `display:none`

Comment: Sorry for not including the `.hidden` class. It simply has `display: none` in it.

Comment: @Dugi - then that should work. Does my simplified example work in your page? If it does then maybe it is something to do with the LESS conversion to CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to just toggle the css class and adjust the visiblity with css only.
(I also would not use ids so extensively. You could use classes instead.)

HTML:

```
<div id="thumb-toggle">Click me</div>
<div id="thumb-options" class="hidden">
  ...
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var $thumb_toggler = $('#thumb-toggle');
$thumb_toggler.click(function(){
  $thumb_toggler.toggleClass('hidden');
});
```

With the first click on `$thumb_toggler` the class `hidden` will be removed from the `#thumb-options` element. With the next click, the `hidden` class will be appended to the list of its classes.

Answer (score 0):

first, try making the class "hide" instead of "hidden"

```
<div id="thumb-options" class="hide">
```

if it still doesn't work try this:

```
<div id="thumb-options" style="display:none;">
```